# React MUI custom select component on mobile throws error

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

Codesandbox link from mui [doc](https://mui.com/base/react-select/#main-content)

https://codesandbox.io/s/izm2c2?file=/demo.js
inspect and try different dimension (phone, ipad or anything) by opening in new window.

I can't find way to resolve this error.

```
Error
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @cursorrux Got it. Question updated

Answer (score 0):

The the problem seems to be with react 18>. Try downgrading to react 17< thats  what fixed the issue for me.

You should post the issue on github as well

Comment: Oh thanks, seems like someone already posted this issue https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33457. Also, any react select dropdown package suggestion ? use case is mostly real estate filters.

Comment: @UmeshJain You can still use the styled version in react 18 from MUI but if you want the unstyled version you could always downgrade if you dont use react 18 features? Personally i needed the custom dropdown so i downgraded.